# List and Numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to hot-encode data.
Data is list of vocabulary_size = 17005207.

To hot-encode, I made a list of inputs of num_labels = 100.
Following code:

```
inputs = []
for i in range(vocabulary_size):
  inputs.append(np.arange(num_labels) == data[i]).astype(np.float32)
```

Throws me an Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

I tried dtype = np.float32 inside append function but again erroneous.
When I try this :

```
inputs = []
for i in range(vocabulary_size):
  inputs.append(np.arange(num_labels) == data[i])
inputs = np.array(inputs,dtype=np.float32)
```

I get correct answer : Hot-Encoded Input Sequence of vocabulary_size x num_labels.
Any Alternative Solution Of One Line Without Using Numpy?
**Solved** :Can I be done directly using numpy array(input) with list(data)? 
**Info about data :** data = np.ndarray(len(words), dtype=np.int32) 
**Reformat function:**

```
  def reformat(data):
      num_labels = vocabulary_size
      print (type(data))
      data = (np.arange(num_labels) == data[:,None]).astype(np.int32)
      return data  
      print (data,len(data))
      return data
```

**New Question : The dimension of data is (vocabulary_size,)...How to convert data using ravel or reshape into dimension of (1,vocabulary_size)?**

Comment: Your error comes from the fact that you are trying to get the `astype` attribute from  what is **returned** by the `inputs.append()` call and that is the None object. In other words you try to call None.astype() which clearly won't work.

Comment: Calm down. With three edits so fast, one cannot answer your question since it changes every second. You seem to understand that ravel or reshape can help you: instead of hurrying to ask in SO, have you tried reading the `numpy.reshape` doc ?

Comment: Sry @YuppieNetworking if it was too much.Just wanted to be clear.I did read the docs.Just wanted exact implementation as where should be parameters to reshape or ravel.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I've understood correctly what you're asking for, but if what you want is a oneliner, you could transform you're already working code into this:

```
inputs = np.array([np.arange(num_labels) == data[i] for i in range(vocabulary_size)], dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: So,you mean to say..there is no other option..but we need to convert data into numpy array only?